# imhist return error with bmp data in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, history.js

I have a image and I want to calculate historgram of it,but this code return error to my ,

```
 I=imread('image number one.bmp');
 imhist(I);
```

and error is

```
??? Error using ==> iptcheckinput
Function IMHIST expected its first input, I or X, to be two-dimensional.

Error in ==> imhist>parse_inputs at 281
iptcheckinput(a, {'double','uint8','int8','logical','uint16','int16','single','uint32',
'int32'}, ...

Error in ==> imhist at 59
[a, n, isScaled, top, map] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

appreciate any help

Comment: can you post the image?

Comment: imhist can work on only 2-D inputs. If your image is a color image your I is going to be 3-D.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, my picture was rgb and imhist work only in 2-D input, I just need convert it to grascale with

```
 I=rgb2gray(I);
```